# How can I use text files in javascript to create objects?

Tags: javascript, python, r, d3.js

I am trying to set up my data in javascript, so I can use some D3.js visualisations.

My input is three tab separated text files, from which i need to extract certain columns and lines of data.

What is the best way to create JSON formatted to use in the JS code. Should I hard code the data into the code, or is it possible to import from my desktop?

I am not primarily a javascript user, although I am familiar with the basic syntax, but I am very comfortable with R and Python.

Alternatively, I can write a Python/R script to format the data, and then use this file in my JavaScript code.

There seems to be a security issue with using files from my desktop?

Comment: Could you please add an example of your text files containing your data? Additionally, please give an example of the desired JSON-formatted output.

Comment: Modern browsers have [File Reader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) for accessing files in user's machine. A traditional way is to have a form with `input type="file"` and send a user-chosen file to your server.

Comment: The files I am using are VCF: http://faculty.washington.edu/browning/beagle/intro-to-vcf.html#example,   BED: http://www.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/bed.html, and .annot, but the latter is less important now. My desired JSON format is:                     [{Name: XX, START:1, STOP:10, SNP:8, Profile[1,0,1,0,1,0], Site:883}, {(repeat)}]

Comment: If you know how to do data manipulation in R, make an R `list` with the structure you need then use `jsonlite::toJSON`.

Comment: Do you want to have all this as a webbased service or just for local/private-use data visualisation? For local usage I would use a Python script to read files and convert data to JSON.

Comment: it would be nice to have as a web-based service, but for this I know i may need to use a server which I don't have access to at the moment. I think I will follow your advice and use either python or R to wrangle the data before converting to JSON. Do I then just copy the JSON file into the code? or can this be accessed locally (sorry for all the assumingly basic Qs)